# Re-enable squamous (zalgo) text in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I have fond memories of 2009, with  text bleeding into lines above and below. People continue to use those combining diacritics to this day, for dramatic effect, but I can no longer enjoy them. Somewhere along the line, Firefox "fixed" that "error" and now all combining characters get smashed together into an ugly, unreadable smudge like in Chrome.

Is there a way to re-enable that way of displaying a font? Am I just using the wrong fonts? I can't find any lists of fonts that "properly" stack combining characters on top of each other. Is there no way to do it, since it leads to some horrible buffer overflow that can't be accounted for? Or is it just disabled by people concluding that nobody could possibly want that to happen?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing now:

[image: not so zalgoy]

And this is what I used to see:

[image: zalgoy]
(from a page I can't link to twice at http :// superuser.com/questions/497262/character-sets-needed-to-properly-display-zalgo)

Comment: Could we have a screenshot of what you're seeing? It's fine for me in Firefox, or at least it looks fine to me. I'm not sure what you're expecting though.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I wrote a little font cycler that showed zalgoified text over a variety of fonts. "Bitstream Vera Sans" and "DejaVu Sans" both stacked the combining characters instead of overlapping them, but no other font that I have did. So, tentatively I'm gonna say: use one of those two fonts (and no other), if you want zalgo text to display in a suitably creepy manner.

They still miss a lot of the upward combining characters though. I'm really at a loss here.